# How to say "In Japan, I want to ..."?

Tags: translation, particle-に, particle-で

I want to say

> In Japan, I want to ride a bullet train.

I have

> にほん で ぼく は しんかんせん を のります。

Is 「にほん で」 correct? Should it be 「にほん に」? Or perhaps something else?

Comment: I would suggest that you edit the English part a bit to say either 'I want to go to Japan to to ride a bullet train' or 'When I go to Japan I want to ride a bullet train', or 'I want to ride a Japanese bullet train', etc.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> 「にほん で ぼく は しんかんせん を のります。」

is a nice attempt.

I would, however, like to address two items here.

「のります」 simply means "***will ride***".  If you want to say "***want to ride***", you might want to say 「のりたいです」.

> 「Verb in Continuative Form + たい」 means "to want to [verb]".

「のり」 is the continuative form of 「のる」.

The next thing I need to point out is the particle choice.  We say 「しんかんせん**に**のる」 and not 「しんかんせん**を**のる」.  That is because 「のる」 is an intransitive verb and thus, it cannot take 「を」.

> is にほん で correct? should it be `にほん に"? Or perhaps something else.

It is correct.  You cannot use 「に」 unless the verb is "stative".  「のる / のりたい」 is not stative.

Stative verbs are 「すむ」(to live), 「いる」(to be),「たいざいする」(to stay), etc.  Those should take 「に」.

Therefore, the correct (by any standard) sentence will be:

> 「にほん **で** ぼく **は** しんかんせん **に** のり**たい**です。」

Comment: "That is because 「のる」 is an intransitive verb and thus, it cannot take 「を」." I'd argue it's the other way around:「のる」happens to not be able to take「を」and therefore it falls into the category we call "intransitive". But maybe that's just me. Also, it's more of a philosophical point.

Answer (score 0):

[l'électeur’s answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/70640/11624) is substantially correct, but since “In Japan” is setting the context for the rest of the sentence, I'd say

> にほん で **は､** ぼく **が**…

And in fact you could probably leave out ぼく が, and just say

> にほん で は､ しんかんせん に のりたい です。

since the listener will infer that the subject of のりたい is ぼく.